# ILogger class is not found in .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-framework-version

while migrate from .netframework to .net core this class is generated and i found error in ILogger and Logtype is not found.
I try to find this class but not found .

```
namespace Namespace1
{

    public class FileLogger : ILogger
    {
        private static readonly string s_Path = "C:\\log.txt";
        public IObfuscationEngine ObfuscationEngine { get; private set; }

        public FileLogger()
        {
            this.ObfuscationEngine = new DefaultObfuscationEngine();

            Clear();
        }

        private static void Clear()
        {
            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(s_Path))
                    File.Create(s_Path);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Cannot write to file: " + s_Path);
            }

            // empty the file to avoid it growing
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(s_Path, string.Empty);

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s_Path, true))
            {
                // write many empty lines to clear the buffers
                for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("");
                }
            }
        }

        public void MethodInfo(
            LogType traceLevel,
            string traceMessage,
            [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
            [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
            [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s_Path, true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("{0} {1}: {2},{3}({4}) - {5}", 
                    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                    traceLevel,
                    memberName, 
                    Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath),
                    sourceLineNumber,
                    traceMessage);
            }
        }

        public void ErrorInfo(
            string traceMessage,
            [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "",
            [CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
            [CallerLineNumber] int sourceLineNumber = 0)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s_Path, true))
            {
                sw.WriteLine("{0} {1}: {2},{3}({4}) - {5}",
                    DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
                    "ERROR",
                    memberName,
                    Path.GetFileName(sourceFilePath),
                    sourceLineNumber,
                    traceMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

first error

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ILogger' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

second error

Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'LogType' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If the project builds fine in .NET Framework, then see where `ILogger` is defined in that version of the project.

Comment: There is no `ILogger` type built-in to the .NET Framework, though it does appear in `Serilog` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` (though both `ILogger` types are incompatible) - but both Serilog and MEL are available for both .NET Framework and .NET Core. I'm assuming you're unfamiliar with changing a project to use .NET Core instead of .NET Framework. Are you recreating your `csproj` file from scratch or something?

Comment: this file is generated at run time when i migrate from framework to core . while in .netframework their is not any file like that

Comment: One approach you can use is to stay with .NET Framework, but change your `csproj` file from the old-style to the new-style (`packageReference`) and after that works then change a few lines to target .NET Core (or .NET Standard).

Comment: "this file is generated at run time when i migrate from framework to core" - what file? How are you performing this "migration"? There are no tools to automatically convert entire projects from .NET Framework to .NET Core.

Comment: i already recreating csproj from scratch

Comment: Yes you are correct their is no tool .i follow from scratch. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/

Comment: are you able to convert csproj file? if is still not working try adding Microsoft.Extensions.Logging package in you solution.

Comment: still same error after installing  Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

Comment: @RAm you have to implement ILogger interface methods also..check my answer

Comment: After adding Microsoft.Extensions.Logging nuget package, don't forget to add `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, the solution for me was adding a reference to the following library in my project:
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions

Comment: Another possible cause of a similar error is using `ILogger` instead of `ILogger<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger .net core must implement Log,IsEnabeld and BeginScope method:

```
public void Log<TState>(LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, TState state, Exception exception, Func<TState, Exception, string> formatter)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

public bool IsEnabled(LogLevel logLevel)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Move logging code to these methods.

Comment: you mean i have to create new ILogger class and implement these method or anything else

Comment: You class is already inherited Ilogger interface, so you should implement these 3 methods

Comment: after inserting these method ILogger error is resolve but still log type error remain.

Comment: seems like log type represents whether event is error or info type. Add this enum to resolve your issue: public enum LogLevel
    {
        INFO,
        ERROR
    } , it will immediately resolve error but you should check value of Logtype in your old application. for time being , you assume there are only 2 type of log error and info.

Comment: public enum LogLevel { INFO, ERROR }  when i write this line in filelogger it generated error

Comment: why we change LogLevel instead of LogType??

Comment: Rename LogLevel to LogType as your convinent

Comment: when i write this one public enum LogType {}; then it work instead if i try to write anything in parenthesis it give me an error i already upvote your answer

Comment: so go ahead with LogType name